# Understanding R's scoping demo

Tags: r, scoping

I try to understand the scoping demo in `R` you can access through `demo(scoping)`.

I do not understand where the `total` variable is saved. First off I thought according to `help("<<-")`

> The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and
>   cause a search to made through parent environments for an existing
>   definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found
>   (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise
>   assignment takes place in the global environment.

it is in the `global environment`. But since I cannot find it there `(ls(environment))` I guess `open.account <- function(total)` creates one total variable for all instances created by an assignment of `open.account()`. But if I create an instance `ross <- open.account(100)` I cannot find the variable.

```
ross
...
<environment: 0x0000000011fbe998>
```

with `ls(environment(environment: 0x0000000011fbe998))`. The result of `getAnywhere(total)` is `no object named ‘total’ was found`. So where do live the different versions of `total`?

Comment: Hint: `ls(environment(ross$balance))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions in the `ross` list are closures., i.e., [functions with data](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#closures). (Technically, most functions in R are closures. But usually you don't care about that.)

All these closures were defined within a call to `open.account`, so they are associated with the same environment "which provides the enclosure of the evaluation frame when the closure is used" (see `help("closure")`).

`total` is defined in this environment.

```
ross <- open.account(100)

environment(ross$deposit)
#<environment: 0x000000000ae10db8>
environment(ross$withdraw)
#<environment: 0x000000000ae10db8>
environment(ross$balance)
#<environment: 0x000000000ae10db8>

environment(ross$deposit)$total
#[1] 100
```